# Javascript não puxa os resultados

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde pessoal,
estou tentando fazer com que calcule novamente utilizando outros tipos de campo, como checkbox e de lista com algumas condições, em alguns tutoriais tentei entender como funciona, porem não consegui fazer gerar o resultado, se poderem dar uma olhada e orientada agradeço.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calcular(oper){
    var tributacao = document.mensalidade.tributacao.value;
    var qt_func = document.mensalidade.qt_func.value;
    var fat_mes = document.mensalidade.fat_mes.value;
    var tipo_emp = document.mensalidade.tipo_emp.value;

    var qt_func2 = qt_func * 20;

    alert (qt_func2);

    var soma = parseInt(qt_func2) + parseFloat(tributacao) + parseInt(prestacao) + parseInt(industrial) + parseInt(comercial) ; 

    if (fat_mes <= 25000){
        var res = parseInt(0) + parseFloat(soma);
    } else (fat_mes > 25000 && fat_mes <= 30000){
        var res = parseFloat(soma) + 115;
    } else (fat_mes > 30000 && fat_mes <= 40000){
        var res = parseFloat(soma) + 150;
    } else (fat_mes > 40000 && fat_mes <= 50000){
        var res = parseFloat(soma) + 190;
    } else (fat_mes > 50000 && fat_mes <= 60000){
        var res = parseFloat(soma) + 230;
    } else (fat_mes > 60000 && fat_mes <= 70000){
        var res = parseFloat(soma) + 270;
    } else (fat_mes > 70000 && fat_mes <= 80000){
        var res = parseFloat(soma) + 310;
    } else (fat_mes > 80000 && fat_mes <= 90000){
        var res = parseFloat(soma) + 350;
    } else (fat_mes > 90000 && fat_mes <= 100000){
        var res = parseFloat(soma) + 390;
    } else (fat_mes > 100000 && fat_mes <= 110000){
        var res = parseFloat(soma) + 430;
    } else (fat_mes > 110000 && fat_mes <= 120000){
        var res = parseFloat(soma) + 470;
    } else (fat_mes > 120000){
        var res = (parseFloat(soma) * 0.40) / 100
    }

    document.mensalidade.res.value = res;
}
</script>

<form name="mensalidade" method="post" action="">
    <label>Tributação</label><br>
        <select id="tributacao" name="tributacao" class="form-control input">
            <option value="0">Escolha</option>
            <option value="49.90">MEI</option>
            <option value="219">Simples Nacional</option>
            <option value="319">Lucro Presumido</option>
            <option value="2650">Lucro Real</option>
        </select><br><br>
    <label>Quantidade de Funcionarios</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="qt_func" id="qt_func"><br><br>
    <label>Faturamento mes</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="fat_mes" id="fat_mes"><br><br>
    <label>Selecione os Tipos</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tipo_emp" id="tipo_emp" value="30">Serviços
    <input type="checkbox" name="tipo_emp" id="tipo_emp" value="150">Industrial
    <input type="checkbox" name="tipo_emp" id="tipo_emp" value="80">Comercial<br><br>
    <input type="text" name="res" id="res"><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Calcular" onClick="calcular(document.mensalidade.fat_mes.value)"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Não entendi, o que deveria acontecer? Explica melhor por favor

Comment: ele deveria multiplicar a qt_func por 20 e somar o restante dos campos e passar pela variavel, somar o valor que esta dentro, porem ele não esta mostrando no campo res...

Comment: Todos os `else` estão errados, deveria ser `else if`. O último poderia ser encurtado para `} else {` (omitindo a condição de comparação, se isso for justificável)

Comment: Tá bem mal explicado, com o perdão da palavra, suponho que o "res" que você se refere é o elemento `<input id="res">`. Do jeito que você escreve as pessoas tem que se esforçar mais pra entender o que você escreveu e o que quer do que entender aonde o seu código falha, ou seja as pessoas perdem muito tempo tentando lhe enteder ao invés de gastarem o tempo tentando encontrar o problema do seu código. Por favor entenda como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: @LuisHenrique bem notado, eu ainda nem havia olhado o código por causa que a pergunta em si estava dificil de entender, boa sacada +1

Comment: @LuisHenrique na verdade o ultimo `else` esta errado também. Todos estão errados.

Comment: De fato a pergunta está bem confusa, não entendi ela também, mas só de bater o olho no código deu pra perceber o erro (não que seja apenas isto). Corrigi a observação do último `else`.

Comment: pessoal desculpa, mais sou novo em javascript e to tentando explicar a maneira que vejo, sei que é algo simples, mais ja estou me matando a uns 4 dias, caçando e tentando fazer o codigo.

Comment: @ViniciusNakamura ninguem tá reclamando do teu código ou teu entendimento de js, estou criticando a maneira que você escreveu mesmo, mas agora esta um pouco mais claro a pergunta depois de conversar, no entanto é um erro de digitação (off-topic), vou até responder, espero que ajude.

Comment: so estou me desculpando, relaxa ;) , pois estou tentando aprender javascript e ta sendo uma luta. rs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

você até começou com o pé direito, isolou o método para calcular em uma função.

Porém aconselho não declarar os eventos inline no proprio HTML, utilize de preferencia no `HtmlElement.addEventListener(name, callback)`.

por fim, apesar de não haver problemas no uso do HTMLCollection para acessar os elementos DOM da pagina no seu exemplo, você pode encontrar algum problema de compatibilidade no futuro, então aconselho utilizar o `document.getElementById`.

```js
//estou assumindo que você definiu estas variaveis em outro ponto do codigo.
var prestacao = 0;
var industrial = 0;
var comercial = 0;

var mensalidade = {};
mensalidade.form = document.querySelector("[name='mensalidade']");
mensalidade.tributacao = mensalidade.form.querySelector("[name='tributacao']");
mensalidade.qt_func = mensalidade.form.querySelector("[name='qt_func']");
mensalidade.fat_mes = mensalidade.form.querySelector("[name='fat_mes']");
mensalidade.tipo_emp = mensalidade.form.querySelectorAll("[name='tipo_emp']");
mensalidade.calcular = mensalidade.form.querySelector("[name='calcular']");
mensalidade.res = mensalidade.form.querySelector("[name='res']");
Object.defineProperty(mensalidade, "tipo_emp_sum", {
  get: function () {
    return [].reduce.call(mensalidade.tipo_emp, function (valor, tipo_emp, indice) {
      if (tipo_emp.checked)
        valor += parseInt(tipo_emp.value);
      return valor;
    }, 0);
  }
});


function calcular(event){
  var tributacao = parseFloat(mensalidade.tributacao.value) || 0;
  var qt_func = parseInt(mensalidade.qt_func.value) || 0;
  var fat_mes = parseInt(mensalidade.fat_mes.value) || 0;  
  var tipo_emp = mensalidade.tipo_emp_sum;
  var qt_func2 = qt_func * 20;

  var soma = qt_func2 + tributacao + tipo_emp + parseInt(prestacao) + parseInt(industrial) + parseInt(comercial) ; 
  var res = soma;
  switch(true) {
    case (fat_mes <= 25000): break;
    case (fat_mes <= 30000): res += 115; break;
    case (fat_mes <= 40000): res += 150; break;
    case (fat_mes <= 50000): res += 190; break;
    case (fat_mes <= 60000): res += 230; break;
    case (fat_mes <= 70000): res += 270; break;
    case (fat_mes <= 80000): res += 310; break;
    case (fat_mes <= 90000): res += 350; break;
    case (fat_mes <= 100000): res += 390; break;
    case (fat_mes <= 110000): res += 430; break;
    case (fat_mes <= 120000): res += 470; break;
    default: res = (res * 0.40) / 100; break;
  }
  mensalidade.res.value = res;
}

//adicionando os eventos aos inputs.
mensalidade.calcular.addEventListener("click", calcular);
mensalidade.tributacao.addEventListener("change", calcular);
mensalidade.qt_func.addEventListener("input", calcular);
mensalidade.fat_mes.addEventListener("input", calcular);
[].forEach.call(mensalidade.tipo_emp, function (tipo_emp, indice) {
  tipo_emp.addEventListener("change", calcular);
})
```

```html
<form name="mensalidade" method="post" action="">
    <label>Tributação</label><br>
        <select id="tributacao" name="tributacao" class="form-control input">
            <option value="0">Escolha</option>
            <option value="49.90">MEI</option>
            <option value="219">Simples Nacional</option>
            <option value="319">Lucro Presumido</option>
            <option value="2650">Lucro Real</option>
        </select><br><br>
    <label>Quantidade de Funcionarios</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="qt_func" id="qt_func"><br><br>
    <label>Faturamento mes</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="fat_mes" id="fat_mes"><br><br>
    <label>Selecione os Tipos</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tipo_emp" id="tipo_emp" value="30">Serviços
    <input type="checkbox" name="tipo_emp" id="tipo_emp" value="150">Industrial
    <input type="checkbox" name="tipo_emp" id="tipo_emp" value="80">Comercial<br><br>
    <input type="text" name="res" id="res"><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Calcular" name="calcular" "/>
</form>
```

Comment: legal, ainda estou tentando entender o codigo que vc fez, so tenho que alterar agora o selecione os tipos para checkbox, pois ele podera escolher mais de 1 serviço no caso. seria o mesmo esquema do radio?

Comment: @ViniciusNakamura, não vai quebrar o código, mas não acho que vai gerar o resultado esperado, acredito que você terá que fazer uma pequena adaptação, como substituir o filter (pega o primeiro selecionado) por um reduce (somar todos os valores selecionados). porém não estou vendo você utilizando o valor de `tipo_emp` no seu script.

Comment: No caso o tipo_emp vai dizer ql o segmento da empresa, ai necessitaria somar eles tbms, caso fossem selecionados, fiz esta alteração aqui, porem não adicionou a diferença no valor final.

Comment: @ViniciusNakamura, realizei uma alteração para somar todos os valores de `tipo_emp` e acresentar os mesmos à `soma`.

Comment: Realizei alguns teste e percebi que na linha default: res = (res * 0.40) / 100; break; não teria que ser fat_mes, pois notei que ele faz um valor totalemente diferente, que no caso seria 1000, aparece 0.12 adicionando o valor de 250000

Comment: Eu também não entendi esta linha, estava completamente fora de sintonia com o resto do codigo, em todo caso apenas transcrevi a sua logica.

Comment: eu fiz uns testes, e alterei uma linha que irei mudar no codigo, que funcionou legal, ou melhor adicionei a soma que ficou assim "default: res = (fat_mes * 0.40) / 100 + soma ; break;"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, vamos ver se eu consigo te ajudar. Os `if`'s estão errados, eles têm que ficar assim como neste exemplo abaixo e inicie a variável `res` antes de entrar nos `if`'s para não precisar ficar iniciando ela a toda hora.

```
var res =0;
if (fat_mes <= 25000){
     res = parseInt(0) + parseFloat(soma);
} else if (fat_mes > 25000 && fat_mes <= 30000){
     res = parseFloat(soma) + 115;
} else if (fat_mes > 30000 && fat_mes <= 40000){
     res = parseFloat(soma) + 150;
} else if (fat_mes > 40000 && fat_mes <= 50000){
     res = parseFloat(soma) + 190;
} else if (fat_mes > 50000 && fat_mes <= 60000){
     res = parseFloat(soma) + 230;
} else if (fat_mes > 60000 && fat_mes <= 70000){
     res = parseFloat(soma) + 270;
} else if (fat_mes > 70000 && fat_mes <= 80000){
     res = parseFloat(soma) + 310;
} else if (fat_mes > 80000 && fat_mes <= 90000){
     res = parseFloat(soma) + 350;
} else if (fat_mes > 90000 && fat_mes <= 100000){
     res = parseFloat(soma) + 390;
} else if (fat_mes > 100000 && fat_mes <= 110000){
     res = parseFloat(soma) + 430;
} else if (fat_mes > 110000 && fat_mes <= 120000){
     res = parseFloat(soma) + 470;
} else if (fat_mes > 120000){
     res = (parseFloat(soma) * 0.40) / 100
}
```

fazendo assim, o erro vai sumir, mas ainda tem a variável `prestacao` que não está definida em lugar algum.

Comment: no final do arquivo defini um alert com a variavel res e mais acima uma outra com a variavel soma, em ambos não aparecem o valor.